# Display time in 24 hour format

Tags: java, datetime

I wanted to get date and time in this format. "2017-02-05 20:20:03".
I used the following code to get the result.
But it didn't work out.

```
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-mm-dd HH:mm:ss").format(new Date()));
```

Comment: Is *"didn't work out"* supposed to be a description of what went wrong? As far as I can see, you got the time in 24 hour format, so what is your problem? *([krock guess below](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42172475/5221149), but your question description sucks)*

Comment: Note: The specific date in your example `2017-02-05` is about a week in the past at the time of this posting. Constructing a date using the no arg constructor i.e. new `Date()` will give you the current date/time.

Answer (score 2):

Your immediate problem is that you used `mm` twice. `MM` is a month.

This works in Java 8.

```
String dt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("uuuu-MM-dd HH:mm:ss").format(LocalDateTime.now);
```

`2017-02-10 23:20:11`

Answer (score 0):

Check the [date and time patterns](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) table; Month is capital `M` and minute is lower `m`.  So your date part should look like this: `yyyy-MM-dd`.

The `SimpleDateFormat` in your code should look like this:

```
new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss")
```

As you can see from the table in the link above, `H` is 24 hour time so this is correct.  Have you checked what timezone your jvm is running in?

Comment: Thanks you for noticing. But the result is still displaying like this. "2017-02-11 10:42:43". I want the time in 24 format.

Comment: `new Date()` will create a new date object for the current time.  The [SimpleDateFormat constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html#SimpleDateFormat(java.lang.String)) you are using will format the date using the default locale.